# Sharepoint sortable gridview rows

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sharepoint, jquery-ui-sortable, sharepoint-clientobject

I´m new to sharepoint development and I´m trying to make a list presented in a gridview sortable. The requirement is that the rows can be reordered in any way and then the change must persist. So far i am able to sort the rows using jquery sortable, but i´m facing two issues:

1) the receive property is not firing for the sortable function, even if i´m just trying displaying an alert

2) i don´t know the sharepoint way of saving the reordered list back to the database in order to make the changes persistent. i´m keeping track of the listitem´s Ids and Title

Please, I would highly appreciate any help or direction regarding this issue, thank you.

Comment: Plz list what have you tried so far.

Comment: I have tried the client object model with sharepoint following [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852596.aspx). Just changed the native HTML5 DnD for the Jquery sortable library and changed the listview for the gridview (which is how the data is currently been presented).

But when calling the SP object i get an error and can´t seem to get past this step to actually save the newly sorted list.